# Restart touch screen without rebooting phone

Tags: cyanogenmod, touchscreen, nexus-6p

Occasionally my screen becomes completely unresponsive to any touch event. Possibly some lower level touch screen driver crashed (?).

Is it possible to *only* restart the touch screen system without rebooting the entire OS?

I am using a Nexus 6P and have root access.

Comment: You're running a Cyanogenmod nightly? It's maybe better to check on their forum.

Comment: Please take note that the community is in progress to [discourage a problem pertaining to a specific nightly build](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/2077). Unless you can clarify that the issue is not specific to nightly, the question might be closed (since we don't have better answer than CM devs). Finally, consider to post the bug on [their bug tracker for nightlies](https://jira.cyanogenmod.org/projects/NIGHTLIES).

Comment: My question is not specific to a nightly build. I removed it as it seems to be confusing. All I wanted to know is if it is possible to restart the touchscreen driver without a full system reboot. I have seen this issue with other phones/ROMs in the past. This is unrelated to any specific ROM.

Comment: Can you try `adb shell su -c 'am restart'` from PC the next time the device freezes and see if the issue persists or resolves? How did you conclude that it is a driver that is causing the freeze? How did you conclude that it is the driver in other ROMs that you've seen having the same issue?

Comment: @Firelord Thanks, I will try this the next time the device freezes and report back here.